# Get phone number for multiple recipients in android

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

In android, when an SMS is sent to more than one recipient, an SMS thread is created. In addition to this, separate entries are created in the SMS table for each SMS, each having the same thread_id. These entries have an 'address' field from which the recipient address can be read.

Question:

Is there a more efficient way to read the recipient addresses from the entry in the thread table itself?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !!!